# How to modify a result in calculation?

Tags: javascript, jquery-calculation

Formula is (val x 0.5) + 50 = result, but if result is greater then 200, then override result to 150

My if is
`if (val > 200) {
       result = 150
    }`

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: What are you looking for help with?

Comment: @bfavaretto it works too well

Comment: So.... what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need a function:

```
function doSomething(val)
 {
   var result = val *.5 + 50;

   if ( result > 200 )
 {
    result = 150;
  }

return result;
}
```

In one line I suppose it would be:

```
var result = (val*.5) + 50 > 200 ? 150 : (val*.5) + 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming if val<= 200, the result will be the real result.

```
    var result = (val * 0.5) +50;

    result = result>200?150:result;
```